# BizTalk REST Get Method in Send Port Web HTTP

Tags: c#, azure, rest, biztalk

I am having an Issue with the GET Call in Send Port , this call have some parameters in the URL. I am using variable mapping for the parameters but i need to know if its right ? Below is the URL and HHTTP Method

```
URL : https://vkbiztalk.wordpress.com/2017/06/17/publish-biztalk-as-rest-service?q=Name=John  (Sample URL )

SendPort Method: <BtsHttpUrlMapping><Operation Name="Call" Method="GET" Url="?%3Fq%3DName={Name}" /></BtsHttpUrlMapping>
```

I am receiving the below error ,

> The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request.
>   URL request parameter ?q=Name cannot be used in this context.".

I tried through the browser and the URL works

Answer (score 1):

In your URL definition you have ? and then a %3F, which is another ?.  That does not match the sample URL you have.

```
URL : https://vkbiztalk.wordpress.com/2017/06/17/publish-biztalk-as-rest-service?q=Name=John  (Sample URL )
URL : https://vkbiztalk.wordpress.com/2017/06/17/publish-biztalk-as-rest-service??q=Name=John  (Actual URL as per your Operation)
```

The actual mapping should either be

```
<BtsHttpUrlMapping><Operation Name="Call" Method="GET" Url="%3Fq%3DName={Name}" /></BtsHttpUrlMapping>
```

or

```
<BtsHttpUrlMapping><Operation Name="Call" Method="GET" Url="?q%3DName={Name}" /></BtsHttpUrlMapping>
```

Comment: Yes right , the URL which i gave is the right one but the method URL was wrong , i figured this out ! The Updated Method will be as below ,                                                                                      <BtsHttpUrlMapping><Operation Name="Call" Method="GET" Url="%3Fq%3DName={Name}" /></BtsHttpUrlMapping>